# Stretching colorbox to the end of line

Tags: color, highlighting

I was just making my resume and I wanted to highlight the different sections. I used the color package. This is the code:

```
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}


\colorbox{Cyan}{\underline{\textbf{Objective}}}

To work in areas like Embedded systems, Hardware Design in an established firm and to apply the knowledge for personal and professional benefit\
```

What I get is something like this:
[image]

What I want is this:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
 \colorbox{whatever}{\rlap{\textbf{Objective}}\hspace{\linewidth}\hspace{-2\fboxsep}}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a definition of `\Colorbox[<width>]{<colour>}{<stuff>}` using [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\Colorbox}{O{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep} m m}{%
  \colorbox{#2}{\makebox[#1][l]{#3}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\noindent\Colorbox{Cyan}{\textbf{Objective}}
\end{document}​
```

The default width `<width>` is `\linewidth-2\fboxsep`, where `\fboxsep` is the gap between the text and the colour box boundary.