# How to make a border for my own environment?

Tags: environments, border, colorbox

```
\documentclass{book}
\title{Introduction to Latex}
\author{Me}
\date{}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{counter-within={chapter}}
\newenvironment{myquestion}
  {\question[name={myExercise}]}
  {\endquestion}


\newlength{\currentparindent}
\newenvironment{myset}
    {   \setlength{\currentparindent}{\parindent}
        \par
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \setlength{\parindent}{\currentparindent}
         \noindent\colorbox{Gray!50}{Exercise \thesubsection  }
        {\color{Black}   \hrule height 0.1ex} \vspace{0.5ex}}
    {

       \end{minipage}
    }  

\begin{document}
    \chapter{first}
        \section{start}
            \subsection{install}
                \begin{myset}
                 \begin{myquestion}
                Review the documentation for your compiler and determine what file naming convention it uses. Compile and Run the main program from page 2.
            \end{myquestion}
                \end{myset}

\end{document}
```

Two question:
First:
I want to make a border for my environment like this
[image]

Second:
How to stretch the colorbox to the end of the line. I know there is an answer to the second question [Stretching colorbox to the end of line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63541/stretching-colorbox-to-the-end-of-line)

But the accepted answer will make the text below the colorbox away from the colorbox, which I don't want.

Comment: Why don't you use `tcolorbox`? That would be easier.

Comment: @TeXnician: I thought that too, but there's an error message when trying to wrap a `tcolorbox` around it: `\__driver_color_pickup_aux:w has an extra }`. I encountered the same error message when trying to use `tasks` within `tcolorbox` recently`...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I know that tcb is okay with xsim, but never tried with exsheets. Probably an issue of wrapping in so many environments.

Comment: @TeXnician: I have not used `xsim` yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a conceptually different version using `xsim` and `tcolorbox`.

[image: xsim]

```
\documentclass{book}
\title{Introduction to Latex}
\author{Me}
\date{}

\usepackage{xsim}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\xsimsetup{solution/print=false}
\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{tcolorbox}{%
    \tcolorbox[enhanced,left=2pt,right=2pt,title=\GetExerciseName~\thesubsection,% append .\GetExerciseProperty{counter} to count inside subsection,
        colback=white,colframe=black,colbacktitle=gray!50,coltitle=black,sharp corners=all]%
}{\endtcolorbox}
\DeclareExerciseType{myset}{
    exercise-env=myset,
    solution-env=mysetsol,
    exercise-name=Exercise,
    solution-name=Solution,
    exercise-template=tcolorbox,
    solution-template=tcolorbox,
    within=chapter,
    the-counter={\arabic{myset}},
}

\newcounter{myquestion}[myset]
\newenvironment{myquestion}
  {\refstepcounter{myquestion}\textbf{Text here \themyquestion}\par}{}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{first}
        \section{start}
            \subsection{install}
                \begin{myset}
                 \begin{myquestion}
                Review the documentation for your compiler and determine what file naming convention it uses. Compile and Run the main program from page 2.
            \end{myquestion}
                \end{myset}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this? These frames, which rely on the `framed` package, can break across pages

```
\documentclass{book}
\title{Introduction to Latex}
\author{Me}
\date{}
\usepackage{framed}

\usepackage[svgnames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{counter-within={chapter}}
\newenvironment{myquestion}
{\question[name={myExercise}]}
{\endquestion}

\newlength{\currentparindent}
\newenvironment{myset}
{\setlength{\currentparindent}{\parindent}
\setlength{\FrameRule}{0.8pt}
\par
%\centering
\framed
\setlength{\parindent}{\currentparindent}\vspace*{-\FrameSep}
\noindent\hspace*{-\dimexpr\FrameSep+\FrameRule}\rlap{\rule[-0.8ex]{\dimexpr\linewidth+2\FrameSep+2\FrameRule}{0.1ex}}
\hspace*{\dimexpr2\FrameRule-\fontdimen2\font}
\colorbox{Gainsboro!60!Lavender}{%
\makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth+\FrameSep+\fontdimen2\font][l]%
{\hspace{\dimexpr\FrameSep+2\FrameRule-\fontdimen2\font} Exercise \thesubsection}
}%
{\vspace{-2ex}}
}
{
\endframed
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{first}
\section{start}
\subsection{install}
\begin{myset}
  \begin{myquestion}
    Review the documentation for your compiler and determine what file naming convention it uses. Compile and Run the main program from page 2.
  \end{myquestion}
\end{myset}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, the text below get far away. And I want a border.

Comment: Do you mean a frame?

Comment: Yes, and I don't want the text below get far away.

Comment: @K.Robert: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Could add a few comments to your code? Thanks.