How to highlight a subsection without destroying the referencing system?
I have to use the following template (all unneeded is removed for the question):
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
  \part{Regelungstechnik}
    Text.
    \chapter{Modellbildung}
              Text.
      \section{Test}
        Text.
      \section{Übungen}
        Text.
        \subsection{}\label{Thermodynamik}
          Der ideal durchmischte Swimmingpool in der Abbildung~\ldots
    \cleardoublepage
    \chapter{Systeme im Zeitbereich}
              Text.
      \section{Test}
        Text.
      \section{Übungen}
        Text.
        \subsection{}
          Der aus der Aufgabe \ref{Thermodynamik} bereits bekannte Swimmingpool aus der Abbildung~\ldots
\end{document}

It is important to compile with LaTeX -> DviPs -> ps2pdf, because the document contains eps and ps figures. The resulting document is (a lecture notes for a module at an university) about 340 pages. It contains two parts and twelve chapters with many sections in the chapters. Every chapter has a section with exercises. Every exercise is a subsection.
So far the given part. My task is to highlight the subsections for better visual orientation. I found so far the following solution:
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor,
            hyperref}
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/turn-on-subsection-numbering-in-memoir
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\colorbox{gray!40}{\rlap{{Aufgabe \arabic{chapter}.\arabic{subsection}}}\hspace{\linewidth}\hspace{-2\fboxsep}}}%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63541/stretching-colorbox-to-the-end-of-line
\begin{document}
  \part{Regelungstechnik}
    Text.
    \chapter{Modellbildung}
              Text.
      \section{Test}
        Text.
      \section{Übungen}
        Text.
        \subsection{}\label{Thermodynamik}
          Der ideal durchmischte Swimmingpool in der Abbildung~\ldots
    \cleardoublepage
    \chapter{Systeme im Zeitbereich}
              Text.
      \section{Test}
        Text.
      \section{Übungen}
        Text.
        \subsection{}
          Der aus der Aufgabe \ref{Thermodynamik} bereits bekannte Swimmingpool aus der Abbildung~\ldots
\end{document}

But this destroys the referencing system (just compile the above code and you will see the problem). I also found a workaround:
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor,
            hyperref}
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/turn-on-subsection-numbering-in-memoir
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\colorbox{gray!40}{\rlap{{Aufgabe \arabic{chapter}.\arabic{subsection}}}\hspace{\linewidth}\hspace{-2\fboxsep}}}%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63541/stretching-colorbox-to-the-end-of-line
\begin{document}
  \part{Regelungstechnik}
    Text.
    \chapter{Modellbildung}
              Text.
      \section{Test}
        Text.
      \section{Übungen}
        Text.
        \subsection{}
          Der ideal durchmischte \hypertarget{Thermodynamik}{Swimmingpool} in der Abbildung~\ldots
    \cleardoublepage
    \chapter{Systeme im Zeitbereich}
              Text.
      \section{Test}
        Text.
        \section{Übungen}
          Text.
          \subsection{}
            Der aus der Aufgabe \hyperlink{Thermodynamik}{2.11} bereits bekannte Swimmingpool aus der Abbildung~\ldots
\end{document}

But this is not really acceptable, because of the manual setting for every reference and in the case of shifting or moving of the exercises (future refactoring) it become unhandy.
So, is there a practical solution for this task without ''hacking'' a lot?
Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

The redefinition of \thesubsection is wrong, you should not add formatting instructions there. You need to change \@seccntformat. memoir has a command for this:
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor,
            hyperref}
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/turn-on-subsection-numbering-in-memoir
\setsecnumformat{\csname specialformat#1\endcsname{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}}
\newcommand\specialformatsubsection[1]{\colorbox{gray!40}{\rlap{{Aufgabe \arabic{chapter}.\arabic{subsection}}}\hspace{\linewidth}\hspace{-2\fboxsep}}}
\begin{document}
  \part{Regelungstechnik}
    Text.
    \chapter{Modellbildung}
              Text.
      \section{Test}
        Text.
      \section{Übungen}
        Text.
        \subsection{}
          Der ideal durchmischte \hypertarget{Thermodynamik}{Swimmingpool} in der Abbildung~\ldots
    \cleardoublepage
    \chapter{Systeme im Zeitbereich}
              Text.
      \section{Test}
        Text.
        \section{Übungen}
          Text.
          \subsection{}
            Der aus der Aufgabe \hyperlink{Thermodynamik}{2.11} bereits bekannte Swimmingpool aus der Abbildung~\ldots
\end{document}


Thank you @Ulrike Fischer for your answer! It does the right thing! But should the pieces \subsection{}Der ideal durchmischte \hypertarget{Thermodynamik}{Swimmingpool} in der Abbildung~\ldots and Der aus der Aufgabe \hyperlink{Thermodynamik}{2.11} bereits bekannte Swimmingpool aus der Abbildung~\ldots look like this \subsection{}\label{Thermodynamik}Der ideal durchmischte Swimmingpool in der Abbildung~\ldots and Der aus der Aufgabe \ref{Thermodynamik} bereits bekannte Swimmingpool aus der Abbildung~\ldots?

Hello @Ulrike Fischer, if I use your answer, the reference numbers have the section counter in it too, for example \ref{Test} gives 2.1.3 in the document. How can I only have the chapter and the subsection counter in the subsection reference number, for example \ref{Test} should give 2.3? Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

redefine \thesubsection to \arabic{chapter}.\arabic{subsection}

Hello @Ulrike Fischer, thank you for your comment! Yes you are absolutely right, see here! I was confused whether it works with memoir to.
